# python: from an existing dataframe, convert epoch to readable timestamp and add to a new column

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, epoch

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to convert a column of epoch time values to readable timestamps.

Below is a sample of the dataframe I'm starting with:

```
            **COORDs                    Epoch_time**
-78.6496222999, 35.7928398208999        1568594961
-78.6835260145, 35.8283383364           1568591361
-78.5917963281, 35.8409603850999        1568587761
-78.6602230965, 35.8868264454999        1568584161
-78.6387225789, 35.793230819            1568573361
```

I would like to convert the Epoch_time column into a readable timestamp then added to a new column in the dataframe called timestamp.

I've used the code: `df[timestamp] = pd.to_datetime(df['Epoch_time'], unit = 'ms')`
and received the below error:

```
    df[timestamp] = pd.to_datetime(df['Epoch_time'], unit = 'ms')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-a9eff940f87e>", line 1, in <module>
    df[timestamp] = pd.to_datetime(df['Epoch_time'], unit = 'ms')

NameError: name 'timestamp' is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes, should be `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Epoch_time'], unit = 'ms')`